# Dynamically added assets prefix in the image URL - Ember-CLI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, gruntjs, ember-cli

I am trying to load the app by using `ember serve`. Some of the images are not found error getting.
In CSS :

```
background-image: url(assets/images/image.svg);
```

its redirected to

> http://localhost:4200/assets/assets/images/image.svg 404 (Not Found)

**because** in this URL two assets name added that's why the image is not found, I don't know where this asset added.

when adding `'/'` in the prefix of URL am able to see the image in the app.

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/image.svg);
```

its redirected to

> http://localhost:4200/assets/images/image.svg - working fine

How to avoid two assets name without using `'/'` as a prefix for assets. Kindly help anyone pls...

Comment: whats wrong with `/assets/images/image.svg`? where did you place the SVG?

Comment: If you look at the guides https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/ you will see that the prescribed way is with an absolute path when referencing assets from css

Comment: you itself provided the answer on how to avoid two assets name. What else you are expecting ?

Answer (score 1):

A URL without a leading slash `/` is a relative URL in CSS as well as known from HTML. The URL is relative to the location of the CSS file not the document the CSS file is imported in. Ember.js puts CSS files in `/assets` in build by default. The application styles are stored in `/assets/appname.css`. Therefor all relative URLs defined in styles are relative to `/assets` folder in build output. Long story short: You shouldn't add `assets/` to a relative URL used in application styles.

Another option is using absolute URLs as suggested in comments but if I got your question right that's not an option for you (e.g. cause the app is not deployed to  document root but a subfolder).